# Continuity from the definition for $f(x)= x^2-x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

> Lef $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)= x^2-x.$ Show directly from the definition that $f$ is continuous at $-1$.

So using the definition:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $\delta >0$ s.t whenever $|x-(-1)| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) -f(-1)| < \varepsilon.$

Now i can come up with the following:

$|f(x) - f(-1)| = |x^2-x-2| = |x-2||x+1|$

but from here I'm not sure how to continue and get $|x-2||x+1|$ to be less than $\delta$ so i could chose an $\varepsilon.$ My initial thought was to use the triangle inequality, but I don't see how we can use it here. Any suggestions?

Comment: The trick is always to check what makes this small, and deal violently with the rest. Here, $|x-2||x+1|$ is small because $|x+1|$ is, and $|x-2|$ is essentially innocuous. To be more precise, you could tell that if $x \in (-2,0)$, then $|x-2| < 4$, and continue.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure i got exactly what you proposed. We have that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so how come we could restrict ourselves to $x \in (-2, 0)$?

Comment: $x$ is supposed to be close to $-1$, namely in $(-1-\delta,-1+\delta)$. If $\delta < -1$, this gives $x \in (-2,0)$. And remember, you want to *find* (or build) such a $\delta$, so you have the right to decide that it is smaller than 1 (or 0.00001, because why not?). See the nice answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimate $|x-2| = |x+1-3|\le |x+1|+|-3| =|x+1|+3 < 4$ if $|x+1| < 1$. Thus choose $\delta = \text{min}(1,\frac{\epsilon}{4})$, then if $|x+1| < \delta \implies |x-2||x+1| < 4\cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{4} = \epsilon\implies |f(x) - f(-1)| < \epsilon\implies f(x)$ is continuous at $x = -1$.